# Can I Put my logo on an outputted PDF?

Tags: pdf, cs5, adobe-acrobat, adobe-creative-suite

I create designs and then export to PDF and give them to the printers, but what I would like to do is to put our company logo on there, but not in the printable area.  I know I can put the file name etc around it but is there a way to put a logo too?  If not, is there a way to put my company name/author name without changing the file name?

Regards,

Eoin

Comment: CS5 & Acrobat 9.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up the document (or by modifying the document setup), include a Slug area of, say 18 points (1/4 inch) on the top edge. You can place anything in that area: text, logo, pictures of your cat, you name it.

When exporting the PDF, turn on "Include Slug Area" in the "Marks and Bleeds" section of the PDF dialog. Anything you have included in the slug area will be visible in the PDF, but because it is outside the bleed, it will not print unless specifically included by the prepress operator in the RIP settings. Even so, it will be trimmed off along with the bleed.

Comment: Legend, thanks a million it is much appreciated.  Now I can brand everything. :)

Answer (score 4):

Well this is a multi-level question so I will answer them accordingly.  Since you have tagged this with [adobe-creative-suite](/questions/tagged/adobe-creative-suite) I would assume you have Acrobat.  Since you did not specify which version of Acrobat you have I will demonstrate with Acrobat X known as Acrobat 10.

> I know I can put the file name etc around it but is there a way to put
>   a logo too?

**Adding a watermark**

- Open the PDF in Acrobat
- On the top right there should be a list of `Tools Comment Share`
- Click `Tools`
- A drop down will appear with a list so click `Pages`
- After you click `Pages` an accordion will open and at the bottom click `Watermark`
- After you click `Watermark` another dropdown will ask you to `Add Watermark`, `Remove`, and `Update`.
- A pop window will appear
- Select the radio buttom of `File` and browse for your logo
- The settings are pretty standard but for printing options click on `Appearance Options`
- In `Appearance Options` a list of three options with a check box will show and you can toggle the first one `Show when printing`.

[image]

---

**Adding what is known as Metadata**

To add metadata we will be using Acrobat.  To open the metadata options for the file do the following:

- Open file in Acrobat
- Click `File > Properties` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and a popup will appear:
- Fill in accordingly

[image]

---

**Automating the process**

In Acrobat 10 they removed what is know as `batch scripting` in later editions of Acrobat and replaced it with what is called the `Actions wizard`.  A great video, [How to use the Action Wizard](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/acrobat-x-tips-tricks/how-to-use-the-action-wizard/), can be found on Adobe TV that shows how to use batch processing.

Comment: Side note: Acrobat supports more file types for use as a watermark than their file dialog suggest (limits). I know for a fact you can use EPS files.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.  Forgive me for being ignorant but the below answer seems easier, is there an advantage to doing things your way?  
  
The disadvantages I see are:  
- I have to open acrobat (the way below I can do it in the current program)  
- Adding a water mark may appear on top of the work making it harder for my clients to approve/sign off the work (I'll test this)    
- It's easier to edit the text as I do not have to create a new jpg/eps/whatever for different projects.  The text is also a vector as opposed to potentially pixels (if using Illustrator or InDesign)